# php - compare date with database (birthdate)

Tags: php

So I have a row called birthday in the database with the value of let's say 2001-04-25 (DATE type).
And I want to see if it's a user birthday.
I get current month and day:

```
$monthday_today = date('m-d');
```

And than do the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d')=".$monthday_today;
```

But it doesn't works, any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the $monthday_today value.

You query (if you would output it) would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') !=  04-2014
```

But this is not a correct SQL query, the query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') !=  '04-2014'
```

The simple solution would be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d')!="."'".$monthday_today."'";
```

---

The good solution would be to use parameterized prepared statements with either positional or named parameters:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') != ?";
```

Or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') != :monthday_today";
```

You don't need to quote parameterized prepared statements because they will infer (deduce) if quoting is necessary or not by the type of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

There's an even simpler solution that doesn't require PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE YEAR(birthday) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(NOW())";
```

Comment: That will work for comparing the clients birthday with today -- but if you move the same logic to a day earlier you're back to square one. And it is plausible to move the logic to another day for example if you want to process birthday vouchers in a cron-job 5 days before the actual birthday and tell the recipients they have 5 days to use the new vouchers.

Comment: I am aware of that but concerning the question it's still an answer :)

Comment: It's an answer but it doesn't really solve the underlying problem, it more like avoids it.

Comment: No, it shows some example usages of build-in MySQL functions, that might be used even in combination with PHP. You could e.g. use a DateTime object and feed it into your query using prepared statements, etc.

Comment: I like this solution, but the it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Anticom -- the underlying problem is composing queries as strings and quoting variables used in queries. You answer may be good but it does avoid the underlying problem. If MarinescuEdward is learning how to use strings as queries and uses your answer he'll be happy until the next time quoting becomes an issue.

Comment: As I already mentioned, he should rather use prepared statements since they kind of solve the problem of injections. That would also solve the problem of having to quote the date expression.

Comment: Are you sure is the correct code? It doesn't output anything for me.

Comment: What column type is `birtday`?

Comment: birthday in the database is DATE type